# Unable to modify property that is being privately set in C#

Tags: c#

I have a couple of properties in the class of type :

```
public string Key { 
    get { return Get<string>("Key", "key"); } 
    private set { tmpValue = value; }
}
```

Now i want to create copy of the object of that class and take only few of those property values and set rest of them to null. But i'm not able to do that even if i explicity set them to null they retain their values.

how can i do this ?

Comment: Have a constructor that sets those properties?

Comment: You don't. That's the whole point of a privately set property. `private set` means that whoever created that class doesn't want anyone else to modify its properties. The only one that can modify them is the class itself. Most likely the class sets those properties in the constructor, in which case you need to pass what you want to the constructor itself

Comment: Post your best attempt that didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can better understand your question.

Comment: Of course it will retain its value. The setter is setting something completely different than what the getter is getting from. If you copy whatever `Get()` is accessing, it won't return `null` even if you set this property `null` in a copy-ctor ....

Comment: Can you post your attempt in full here? Also you had Get<String> instead of Get<String, String>

Comment: You probably want to show what `Get`-does, since that property definition looks a bit odd. You might also want to describe what the actual goal is to avoid X/Y problems. Setting a bunch of properties to null also sounds odd, and may indicate you should use another type.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is the `set` for the property only assigns to a temporary or throw-away location. One wonders why there's even a `set` definition here at all, since building a property with only a  `get` is also legal (unless `tmpValue` is also a property with a complicated `set` definition). It seems the actual property data is really stored in a dictionary of some kind that looks up the value by name, rather than a real backing field.

To set the property, even in a member-method for the type, you need to look at the `Get<T>()` method to see how it retrieves the property data. Then do the reverse.

Note storing property data this way is an anti-pattern or code smell in the first place — something to avoid. It makes property access for the class slower and subject to potential run-time errors that are not caught at compile time as normal if you ever have a typo in a property definition.